# Deallocating an array causes an exit 11 code

Tags: c++, pointers, destructor

I am building a project that is composed of Vehicle, Showroom, and Dealership. I've built the classes, and I am testing out my method GetAveragePrice()

```
float Dealership::GetAveragePrice()
```

This method was working perfectly:

```
Dealership dealership("COP3503 Vehicle Emporium", 3);
dealership.AddShowroom(&showroom);
dealership.AddShowroom(&secondary);
dealership.AddShowroom(&third);

cout << "Using just the GetAveragePrice() function\n\n";

cout << "Average price of the cars in the dealership: $" << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2);
cout << dealership.GetAveragePrice();
```

The output would be

```
Using just the GetAveragePrice() function

Average price of the cars in the dealership: $27793.60
```

This is the expected output I wanted, but I was told I have memory leaks and must include a destructor to deallocate my *Showroom *showroomList* pointer (which I initialized as the following in the Dealership constructor):

```
this->showroomList = new Showroom[maxNumOfShowrooms];
```

So I write my destructor as the following:

```
Dealership::~Dealership()
{
    delete [] showroomList;
}
```

Now, there aren't any memory leaks, but I don't get the expected output and an exit code 11:

```
Using just the GetAveragePrice() function


Process finished with exit code 11
```

Does anyone know why this destructor is messing up my output?

Comment: Try using a unique_ptr instead. If everything works, then there could be duplicated deleting or similar error (in a copy constructor just passing ptr but still deleting it in new copy destructor) in your original code.

Comment: I recommend producing a [mcve]. If that doesn't show you the problem and allow you to fix it, post the MCVE here. Right now there are a lot of things that could be going on and you have to narrow the scope.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik I do a deep copy of showroomList in my copy constructor though

Comment: @Pablo and you forbid its double deletion by some checking?

Comment: Did you do the same in the assignment operator (or take advantage of the copy constructor via the Copy and Swap Idiom)?

Comment: Looking at this with an XY solution, are you allowed to replace `Showroom* showroomList` with `std::vector<Showroom> showroomList`? If nothing else `vector`s [Rule of Five](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) compliance should eliminate many possible problems and the `at` method will help with detecting out of bounds accesses.

Comment: Note that "exit code 11" in this case means your code threw signal number 11 which is a "segmentation fault" which is caused by trying to access a memory segment in a way you aren't allowed to. This is usually a buffer overflow, accessing a deleted variable, deleting a variable twice or other similar bugs. Difficult to tell which without a [mcve], if you try to produce a MCVE you might find in the process where your bug is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version would delete only once by the last instance standing, in its destructor.

```
std::unique_ptr<ShowRoom> Dealership::showroomList;

Dealership::Dealership(size_t maxNumOfShowrooms)
           :showroomList(std::unique_ptr<ShowRoom>(new Showroom[maxNumOfShowrooms]))
{

}

Dealership::~Dealership()
{
    // auto deleted here, with reverse order of initialization
}
```

but you have a new and delete pair so you should check for deletion only once. This would need some global counter outside of class (or its static variable) and this may not be as readable as smart pointer.

If you are using multiple threads with this, then you could be better with shared_ptr and a custom deleter (`[](T * ptr){delete [] ptr;}`) as its second constructor parameter.

At least this way you can know if error is about new and delete.